# Angular 5 Property 'submenu' does not exist on type

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-services

I just created the service to generate the "Menu", I used to call the method from components and i add some more menu this is work flow.

Here menu.service.ts file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Api } from '../_providers/api/api';

@Injectable()
export class MenuService {

    menuLinks = [
        {
            label: "Dashboard",
            details: "12 New Updates",
            routerLink: "dashboard",
            iconType: "pg",
            iconName: "home",
            thumbNailClass: "bg-success"
        },
        {
            label: "Email",
            details: "234 New Emails",
            routerLink: "email/list",
            iconType: "pg",
            iconName: "mail"
        },
         {
            label: "Classroom",
            iconType: "pg",
            iconName: "laptop",
            toggle: "close",
            submenu: [
                {
                    label: "Classroom UI Test",
                    routerLink: "classroom/class",
                    iconType: "letter",
                    iconName: "AC",
                },
                {
                    label: "Grades",
                    routerLink: "classroom/grade-list",
                    iconType: "fa",
                    iconName: "graduation-cap",
                }
            ]
        }]


    private menuList = new BehaviorSubject(this.menuLinks)
    currentMenuList = this.menuList.asObservable();

    constructor(public Api: Api) {
        this.getAllCourse();
    }


    addCourseinMenu(courseInfo) {
        console.log("adding new course");
        this.menuLinks.forEach(function (menuObj) {
            if (menuObj.label === "Classroom") {
                menuObj.submenu.push({
                    label: courseInfo.shortName,
                    routerLink: "classroom/" + courseInfo.courseId,
                    iconType: "letter",
                    iconName: courseInfo.name.slice(0, 2).toUpperCase(),
                })
            }
        })
        this.menuList.next(this.menuLinks);
    }

    getAllCourse() {
        let that = this;
        console.log("checking all course");
        this.Api.getAll('getAllCouseNameandId').subscribe((response) => {
            const courseInfo: any = response;
            courseInfo.forEach(function (courseObj) {
                let name = courseObj.name;
                that.menuLinks.forEach(function (menuObj) {
                    if (menuObj.label === "Classroom") {
                        menuObj.submenu.push({       //Error Line
                            label: courseObj.shortName,
                            routerLink: "classroom/" + courseObj._id,
                            iconType: "letter",
                            iconName: name.slice(0, 2).toUpperCase(),
                        })
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    }
}
```

When i run i got this error

Failed to compile.

src/app/_services/menu.service.ts(400,25): error TS2339: Property 'submenu' does not exist on type '{ label: string; details: string; routerLink: string; iconType: string; iconName: string; thumbNa...'.
  Property 'submenu' does not exist on type '{ label: string; details: string; routerLink: string; iconType: string; iconName: string; thumbNa...'.
src/app/_services/menu.service.ts(420,33): error TS2339: Property 'submenu' does not exist on type '{ label: string; details: string; routerLink: string; iconType: string; iconName: string; thumbNa...'.
  Property 'submenu' does not exist on type '{ label: string; details: string; routerLink: string; iconType: string; iconName: string; thumbNa...'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use fat array `=>` instead of `function` for this

```
  getAllCourse() {
    let that = this;
    console.log("checking all course");
    this.Api.getAll('getAllCouseNameandId').subscribe((response) => {
      const courseInfo: any = response;
      courseInfo.forEach((courseObj:any) {
        let name = courseObj.name;
        this.menuLinks.forEach((menuObj:any) {
          if (menuObj.label === "Classroom") {
            menuObj.submenu.push({       //Error Line
              label: courseObj.shortName,
              routerLink: "classroom/" + courseObj._id,
              iconType: "letter",
              iconName: name.slice(0, 2).toUpperCase(),
            })
          }
        })
      })
    })
  }
```

Comment: ERROR in src/app/_services/menu.service.ts(400,25): error TS2339: Property 'subm
enu' does not exist on type '{ label: string; details: string; routerLink: strin
g; iconType: string; iconName: string; thumbNa...'.
  Property 'submenu' does not exist on type '{ label: string; details: string; r
outerLink: string; iconType: string; iconName: string; thumbNa...'.
src/app/_services/menu.service.ts(420,33):

Comment: I have tried your code same error. the error line is "menuObj.submenu.push()" submenu does not exit on type.

Comment: Super now it's fine

Comment: Okay please tell me

Comment: If I call getAllCourse() method again it puts duplicate entry again how to prevent that

Comment: Sorry Stackblitz not possible now

Comment: if i call "getAllCourse()" method i get data from server and push in "this.menuLinks" if i call two time's it will push again the same data.

Comment: What is the data of `this.Api.getAll('getAllCouseNameandId')` from server?

Comment: [
    {
        "_id": "5b863d234e9b92196496c3be",
        "name": "Course 1 SH2 ",
        "courseId": "12121",
        "shortName": "C1SH2"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b867142353d05184c79266a",
        "name": "Course 2 SH2",
        "courseId": "1215125",
        "shortName": "C2SH2"
    }
]

Comment: `addCourseinMenu` what is the use of this method?

Comment: change this method

this.menuLinks.forEach((menuObj: any) => {
        if (menuObj.label === "Classroom") {
          let checkMenyExist = menuObj.submenu.find((objData: any) => courseObj.shortName == objData.label);
          if (!checkMenyExist) {
            menuObj.submenu.push({       //Error Line
              label: courseObj.shortName,
              routerLink: "classroom/" + courseObj._id,
              iconType: "letter",
              iconName: name.slice(0, 2).toUpperCase(),
            })
          }

        }
      })

Comment: I already done that to fix right now, but what iam looking is if call the getAllCourse() method the top declared variable menuLinks must be considered as new and try to push submenu, because "shortname" isn't unique one it's an abbreviations of course name it will be same for some other courses, anyway thanks @krishna thanks a lot